# Sum values in each column and random row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have big table with data (about 100 colums and 50 rows), and I'm searcing for a way to take one random number in each column and sum there together. So for example if I have a table:

```
 11 21 31 41
 12 22 32 42
 13 23 33 43
 14 24 34 44 
 15 25 35 45
```

Result will be like =12+25+34+41. Is it plausoble?

Answer (score 0):

In a formula:

```
=indirect("A" & ceiling(rand()*50, 1)) + indirect("B" & ceiling(rand()*50, 1)) + indirect("C" & ceiling(rand()*50, 1))...
```

I'd like to think there is a prettier way to do that, but that's the jist of it.

In a UDF:

```
Function randSum(tableRange As Range) As Integer
    Dim colRange As Range

    For Each colRange In tableRange.Columns()
        randSum = randSum + colRange.Rows(Rnd() * colRange.Rows.Count)
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try UDF:

```
Function SUM_RANDOM(rng As Range)
Dim i As Long
Application.Volatile

For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    SUM_RANDOM = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SUM_RANDOM, rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(Int(Rnd() * rng.Rows.Count), i - 1).Value)
Next i

End Function
```